# MySQL Query for Spread/Difference of Energy Counter and missing Value interpolation

Tags: sql, mysql, interpolation, difference, linear-interpolation

I have an energy counter (kWh) recorded in a MySQL database every 15 minutes.
Sometimes the recording fails for several reasons (power outage, computer reboot for updates...) and values are missing.

The table looks as followed:

```
id      Time                Energy
27800   13.02.2024 23:30:01 651720048
27801   13.02.2024 23:45:00 651720672
(missing)
27802   14.02.2024 00:15:02 651721917
27803   14.02.2024 00:30:00 651722540
27804   14.02.2024 00:45:00 651723129
27805   14.02.2024 01:00:02 651723769
27806   14.02.2024 01:15:01 651724405
27807   14.02.2024 01:30:01 651725030
(missing)
27808   14.02.2024 02:00:01 651726275
27809   14.02.2024 02:15:02 651726880
27810   14.02.2024 02:30:01 651727519
27811   14.02.2024 02:45:00 651728130
27812   14.02.2024 03:00:02 651728751
27813   14.02.2024 03:15:02 651729381
```

I am looking for a SQL query which returns the consumption (spread/difference between energy counter values) in a certain (variable) time span (eg. 15 minutes, 60 minutes, 24 hours, 1 month...) which also considers missing values by interpolation.

The result should look as showed there in the columns `Consumption 15m` and `Consumption 1h`:

```
id      Time                Energy      Consumption 15m     Consumption 1h
27800   13.02.2024 23:30:01 651720048   -   
27801   13.02.2024 23:45:00 651720672   624 
(missing)                   651721294.5 622.5               -
27802   14.02.2024 00:15:02 651721917   622.5   
27803   14.02.2024 00:30:00 651722540   623 
27804   14.02.2024 00:45:00 651723129   589 
27805   14.02.2024 01:00:02 651723769   640                 2474,5
27806   14.02.2024 01:15:01 651724405   636 
27807   14.02.2024 01:30:01 651725030   625 
(missing)                   651725652.5 622.5   
27808   14.02.2024 02:00:01 651726275   622.5               2506
27809   14.02.2024 02:15:02 651726880   605 
27810   14.02.2024 02:30:01 651727519   639 
27811   14.02.2024 02:45:00 651728130   611 
27812   14.02.2024 03:00:02 651728751   621                 2476
27813   14.02.2024 03:15:02 651729381   630
```

I guess it is somewhow required to find the closest two values of two given time points (e.g. 14.02.2024 00:00:00 and 14.02.2024 01:00:00) and create an interpolated value of the energy counter to build then the difference of it.

Which query could achieve that desired result?

Comment: Left join your data to a calendar table of all the needed time points and then interpolate as requested

Answer (score 2):

See example.

Recursive add missing rows with interpolated time and energy.

```
with recursive r as( -- anchor part - all existing rows
select id, Time,Energy  
    -- time diff rounded to 15 min intervals count
  ,round(time_to_sec(timediff(lead(time,1,time)over(order by time),time))/900) td15mr
  ,lead(Energy,1,Energy)over(order by time)-Energy eDiff
from test
  union all  -- recursive part  add missing rows only
select id, addtime(Time,'00:15:00'),Energy+(eDiff/td15mr)   
  ,td15mr-1  as td15mr
  ,eDiff-(eDiff/td15mr)
from r where td15mr>1
)
select id, Time,Energy
  ,Energy-lag(Energy,1,Energy)over(order by time) cons15m
  ,case when minute(date_add(time,INTERVAL 1 minute))<15 then
     energy-(min(energy)over(order by time rows between 4 preceding and current row) )
   end cons1h
  ,td15mr,eDiff
from r
order by time;
```

For test data

```
create table test (id int,Time datetime, Energy double);
insert into test values
 (27800   ,'2024.02.13 23:30:01', 651720048)
,(27801   ,'2024.02.13 23:45:00', 651720672)
-- (missing)
,(27802   ,'2024.02.14 00:15:02', 651721917)
,(27803   ,'2024.02.14 00:30:00', 651722540)
,(27804   ,'2024.02.14 00:45:00', 651723129)
,(27805   ,'2024.02.14 01:00:02', 651723769)
,(27806   ,'2024.02.14 01:15:01', 651724405)
,(27807   ,'2024.02.14 01:30:01', 651725030)
-- (missing)
 ,(27808   ,'2024.02.14 02:00:01', 651726275)
,(27809   ,'2024.02.14 02:15:02', 651726880)
,(27810   ,'2024.02.14 02:30:01', 651727519)
,(27811   ,'2024.02.14 02:45:00', 651728130)
,(27812   ,'2024.02.14 03:00:02', 651728751)
,(27813   ,'2024.02.14 03:15:02', 651729381)
,(27814   ,'2024.02.14 03:29:58', 651729400)
  -- missing 3 rows
,(27815   ,'2024.02.14 04:30:02', 651731800)
;
```

Output is

| id | Time | Energy | cons15m | cons1h | td15mr | eDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27800 | 2024-02-13 23:30:01 | 651720048 | 0 | null | 1 | 624 |
| 27801 | 2024-02-13 23:45:00 | 651720672 | 624 | null | 2 | 1245 |
| 27801 | 2024-02-14 00:00:00 | 651721294.5 | 622.5 | 1246.5 | 1 | 622.5 |
| 27802 | 2024-02-14 00:15:02 | 651721917 | 622.5 | null | 1 | 623 |
| 27803 | 2024-02-14 00:30:00 | 651722540 | 623 | null | 1 | 589 |
| 27804 | 2024-02-14 00:45:00 | 651723129 | 589 | null | 1 | 640 |
| 27805 | 2024-02-14 01:00:02 | 651723769 | 640 | 2474.5 | 1 | 636 |
| 27806 | 2024-02-14 01:15:01 | 651724405 | 636 | null | 1 | 625 |
| 27807 | 2024-02-14 01:30:01 | 651725030 | 625 | null | 2 | 1245 |
| 27807 | 2024-02-14 01:45:01 | 651725652.5 | 622.5 | null | 1 | 622.5 |
| 27808 | 2024-02-14 02:00:01 | 651726275 | 622.5 | 2506 | 1 | 605 |
| 27809 | 2024-02-14 02:15:02 | 651726880 | 605 | null | 1 | 639 |
| 27810 | 2024-02-14 02:30:01 | 651727519 | 639 | null | 1 | 611 |
| 27811 | 2024-02-14 02:45:00 | 651728130 | 611 | null | 1 | 621 |
| 27812 | 2024-02-14 03:00:02 | 651728751 | 621 | 2476 | 1 | 630 |
| 27813 | 2024-02-14 03:15:02 | 651729381 | 630 | null | 1 | 19 |
| 27814 | 2024-02-14 03:29:58 | 651729400 | 19 | null | 4 | 2400 |
| 27814 | 2024-02-14 03:44:58 | 651730000 | 600 | null | 3 | 1800 |
| 27814 | 2024-02-14 03:59:58 | 651730600 | 600 | 1849 | 2 | 1200 |
| 27814 | 2024-02-14 04:14:58 | 651731200 | 600 | null | 1 | 600 |
| 27815 | 2024-02-14 04:30:02 | 651731800 | 600 | null | 0 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S7VPRrbl)

Comment: Nice job, it even works with multiple lines missing in a row.
Is there a chance to get such a SQL query working on a MySQL 5.7 server which does not support the 'with' clause?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.7, where windows functions not applicable, we use self join on on a value that precisely defines the order of the rows. We assume that the Id column satisfies this requirement and we can calculate the previous value (`on (t2.id+1)=t1.id`).
If we can't do that, we'll have to do SELF JOIN and GROUP BY to detect previous row or rows.
Or `(select max(Id) from test t2 where t2.time<t.time) as prevId` and join `on id=prevId` - this is lag() row.
Or `(select min(Id) from test t2 where t2.time>t.time) as nextId` and join `on id=nextId` - this is lead() row.

```
select id
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)>1 then date_add(Time,interval -(n-1)*15 minute) else Time end Time
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)>1 then Energy-(eDiff/td15mr)*(n-1) else energy end energy
  ,case when td15mr>1 then (eDiff/td15mr) else eDiff end cons15m
  ,n,td15mr
  from(
   select t1.id, t1.Time,t1.Energy  
    ,round(time_to_sec(timediff(t1.time,coalesce(t2.time,t1.time)))/900) td15mr
    ,t1.Energy-coalesce(t2.Energy,t1.Energy) eDiff
   from test t1
   left  join test t2 on (t2.id+1)=t1.id
  )a
  left join (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 
             union all select 4 union all select 5)nn
  on nn.n<=a.td15mr
```

To calculate hour consumption, self join above query.
There added column `round(to_seconds(time)/900) intN` - interval number for every 15 min intervals. JOIN on intN=(intN-4) - 1 hour=4 intervals

```
select t1.id, t1.Time,t1.Energy,t1.cons15m,t1.energy-t2.energy cons1h -- ,t1.intN,t2.*
from(
 select * ,cast(round(to_seconds(time)/900) as signed) intN
 from(
  select id
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)>1 then date_add(Time,interval -(n-1)*15 minute) else Time end Time
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)>1 then Energy-(eDiff/td15mr)*(n-1) else energy end energy
  ,case when td15mr>1 then (eDiff/td15mr) else eDiff end cons15m
  ,n,td15mr
  from(
   select t1.id, t1.Time,t1.Energy  
    ,round(time_to_sec(timediff(t1.time,coalesce(t2.time,t1.time)))/900) td15mr
    ,t1.Energy-coalesce(t2.Energy,t1.Energy) eDiff
   from test t1
   left  join test t2 on (t2.id+1)=t1.id
  )a
  left join (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 
             union all select 4 union all select 5)nn
    on nn.n<=a.td15mr
 )b
)t1
left join 
  (
 select * ,cast(round(to_seconds(time)/900) as signed) intN
 from(
  select id
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)>1 then date_add(Time,interval -(n-1)*15 minute) else Time end Time
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)>1 then Energy-(eDiff/td15mr)*(n-1) else energy end energy
  ,case when td15mr>1 then (eDiff/td15mr) else eDiff end cons15m
  ,n,td15mr
  from(
   select t1.id, t1.Time,t1.Energy  
    ,round(time_to_sec(timediff(t1.time,coalesce(t2.time,t1.time)))/900) td15mr
    ,t1.Energy-coalesce(t2.Energy,t1.Energy) eDiff
   from test t1
   left  join test t2 on (t2.id+1)=t1.id
  )a
  left join (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 
             union all select 4 union all select 5)nn
  on nn.n<=a.td15mr
 )b
)t2 on (t2.intN)=(t1.intN-4)
order by t1.id,t1.time,t1.n
```

Subqueries t1 and t2 there identic.

Output

| id | Time | energy | cons15m | cons1h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27800 | 2024-02-13 23:30:01 | 651720048 | 0 | null |
| 27801 | 2024-02-13 23:45:00 | 651720672 | 624 | null |
| 27802 | 2024-02-14 00:00:02 | 651721294.5 | 622.5 | null |
| 27802 | 2024-02-14 00:15:02 | 651721917 | 622.5 | null |
| 27803 | 2024-02-14 00:30:00 | 651722540 | 623 | 2492 |
| 27804 | 2024-02-14 00:45:00 | 651723129 | 589 | 2457 |
| 27805 | 2024-02-14 01:00:02 | 651723769 | 640 | 2474.5 |
| 27806 | 2024-02-14 01:15:01 | 651724405 | 636 | 2488 |
| 27807 | 2024-02-14 01:30:01 | 651725030 | 625 | 2490 |
| 27808 | 2024-02-14 01:45:01 | 651725652.5 | 622.5 | 2523.5 |
| 27808 | 2024-02-14 02:00:01 | 651726275 | 622.5 | 2506 |
| 27809 | 2024-02-14 02:15:02 | 651726880 | 605 | 2475 |
| 27810 | 2024-02-14 02:30:01 | 651727519 | 639 | 2489 |
| 27811 | 2024-02-14 02:45:00 | 651728130 | 611 | 2477.5 |
| 27812 | 2024-02-14 03:00:02 | 651728751 | 621 | 2476 |
| 27813 | 2024-02-14 03:15:02 | 651729381 | 630 | 2501 |
| 27814 | 2024-02-14 03:29:01 | 651729400 | 19 | 1881 |
| 27815 | 2024-02-14 03:45:02 | 651730000 | 600 | 1870 |
| 27815 | 2024-02-14 04:00:02 | 651730600 | 600 | 1849 |
| 27815 | 2024-02-14 04:15:02 | 651731200 | 600 | 1819 |
| 27815 | 2024-02-14 04:30:02 | 651731800 | 600 | 2400 |
| 27816 | 2024-02-14 04:38:02 | 651731999 | 199 | 1999 |
| 27817 | 2024-02-14 04:45:02 | 651732200 | 201 | 2200 |
| 27818 | 2024-02-14 05:00:02 | 651732500 | 300 | 1900 |
| 27818 | 2024-02-14 05:15:02 | 651732800 | 300 | 1600 |

[Query is a longread. See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LrwMgZUJ)